# get clicked value from listview

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have created a dynamical listview with jQuery Mobile and I want to get the value of the clicked list item.
The reason I want to achieve this is because I need this value to link to another page and show more details about the clicked item.

I already have searched around the internet and I found a solution which doesn't work for me.

My (jQuery Mobile) page looks like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="personList">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>header</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        footer
    </div>
</div>
```

My function to dynamically add items to the listview looks like this:

(I used HTML5 SQL web storage to store data local on a device)

```
function showPersons() 
{
  db.transaction (function (transaction)
  {
//get data from table
var sql = "SELECT * FROM person";
transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined, 

//loop through sql result and add results to html variable
function (transaction, result)
{
  var html = "<ul id=" + "personListview" + "data-role=" + "listview" +" data-filter=" + "true" + ">";


  if (result.rows.length) //if there is something found
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) 
    {
      var row = result.rows.item (i);
      var voorNaam = row.voorNaam;
      var achterNaam = row.achterNaam;
      var email = row.email;

        html += "<li data-theme='e'" + "data-name='test value'>" + "<a href='#'>" +  "<h3>" + voorNaam + " " + achterNaam + "</h3><p>" + email + "</p></a></li>";

    }
  }
  else //if there is nothing found
  {
    html += "<li> No persons found </li>";
  }

  html += "</ul>";

  //Change page
  $("#personList").unbind ().bind ("pagebeforeshow", function ()
  {
    var $content = $("#personList div:jqmData(role=content)");
    $content.html (html);
    var $ul = $content.find ("ul");
    $ul.listview ();
  });

  $.mobile.changePage ($("#personList"));

}, error);});}
```

As you can see, I added "data-name='test value'" to the "li" tags so I should get this value with the following function:

```
$('#personListview').children('li').click(function() {
alert($(this).attr('data-name')); });
```

However, this last function doesn't work. Nothing happens when I click at an "li" item.
I would expect I get an alert with the value of "data-name").

PS. even when I have declared this, I doesn't get an alert:

```
$('#personListview').children('li').click(function() {
    alert('test');
```

Could someone help me? I am a beginner with Javascript and jQuery(mobile).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: u get any error in error console?

Comment: Does your second page loads dynamically? Or is it static content? You want this data to set a link or recognise something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your click event to something like this (I suggest and assume that your `<ul>` has a class which is `yourclass`):

```
$("#personlist").live('pageinit', function() {   
    $('.yourclass').live('vclick', function(e) {
         alert($(this).attr('data-name').val();
    }  
}
```

Check also this line in your current code:

```
alert($(this).attr('data-name').val();
```

Look at your `<li>` definition. It should start with `<li>`:

```
<li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
```

Your html formatting may not proper. Try to do it as showed in my example:

```
<li><a class="yourclass" href="#" id="' + id + '" ><h1>' + label + '</h1><p>'+ customer + '</p></a></li>
```

Try to change your html `<li>` item, then add event handler:

```
$("#personlist").live('pageinit', function() {   
    $('.yourclass').live('vclick', function(e) {
        alert($(this).attr('data-name').val();
    }  
}
```

In case of formatting problems check this out: [jQuery Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response!
With a "normal" listview, your solution works fine. With my dynamically filled listview it doesn't work for some reason. I don't know why. There happens nothing when I click at a "li" item. 
I created the same page with static list items within the listview and then it works great.

Comment: Did you add class attribute to all li elements dynamically in your code?

Comment: Did you add class=class dynamically to your li items?

Comment: I thought I only had to add class to the "ul" element.

My "ul" now looks like this:
 var html = '<ul id="persoonListview "data-role="listview "data-filter="true" "class="myClass">';

My "il" elements look like this:
html += "<li data-theme='e'" + "data-name='testdata'>" +"<a href='#'>" +  "<h3>" + attribute1 + " " + attribute2 + "</h3><p>" + attribute3 + "</p></a></li>";

The function you suggested:
 $("#personList").live('pageinit', function() {   
    $('.myClass').live('vclick', function(e) {
         //alert($(this).attr('data-name'));
   alert('test');
    });  
});

Comment: What would the function be if I add "class=class" to all "li" elements?

Comment: this is an universal function '.yourclass' means that funcion is binded to all elements with class="yourclass". Review my updated answer, read it carefully. It will surely be an asswer to your problem. In case of problem write another comment.

Comment: It works now! I added class=class to all the "li" elements. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
"<ul id=" + "personListview" + "data-role...
```

outputs to:

```
<ul id=personListviewdata-role...
```

Your javascript needs to read:

```
'<ul id="personListview" data-role=....'
```

Notice that I'm using single quotes at the beginning so I can use double quotes throughout.

Also, I would recommend giving each `<ul>` its own ID, or using a CSS class on it and then binding the event with `$('.myclass').click(function() { ... });`

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I have the "ul" changed to:
var html = '<ul id="persoonListview " data-role="listview " data-filter="true">';

I only have one "ul" which already have an ID.

Although, It still does not work.

Comment: Another suggestion: you may want to look at using a template engine such as jsRender to handle this. Such an engine would let you build a template in HTML instead of concatenating string values together, and then you can render the output with a javascript object. Take a look: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender

Comment: Here's some more info on that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882454.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myListview").on("click", "li", function() { 
     alert( $(this).attr("data-name") ); 
};
```